# How is dot product defined for higher dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I am specifically interested in the case of 2D (matrices). I am reading a research paper which says that I should find the dot product of matrix A and its transpose and subtract it from the identity matrix.

$AA^T - I$

From the matrix library I am using the dot product comes out to be a single number?

Can anyone explain why it would be a matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you quote what the research paper directly? Or better yet, link the paper itself?

Comment: A very common norm is $\|A \| = \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(A A^{t})}$. Perhaps you meant this?

Comment: This might refer to Maple notation?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03130 Equation 8

Comment: I think the paper should not have used the word "dot" there. It's just the product of $A$ and $A^T$.

Comment: In the paper the standard matrix multiplication  is used. Just cross the 'dot'. Maybe the author did that mistake, because the Frobenius norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the induced norm of the Frobenius inner product $A:B=(A,B)_{F}=\sum_{i,j}a_i,b_i$. Which is the analogous of the  vector dot product for matrices.

Comment: There is no dot product defined on matrices, even in packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sort of weird for the paper to call the operation "dot product" because that name is usually reserved for the dot product of two *vectors*. What the paper is talking about, I believe, is simply the standard [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) which, if the matrix is a single column, is the same as the dot product.

So yeah, to describe the formula

$$AA^T-I$$

I would say you simply take the product of $A$ and $A^T$ and subtract $I$.